# garagedoorjQuery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

I'm using garagedoorjQuery in my drupal page. Can somebody tell me, why this code doesn't work like here? http://www.gayadesign.com/scripts/jquerygaragedoor/

```
    <link href='/css/garagedoor.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/js/garagedoorjQuery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


            <div class='garagedoor' id='garagedoor'>        
                <div title='http://www.dasda.com' class='item'>
                    <div class='underlay'>
                        SOMETHING ABOUT ME
                    </div>
                    <img src='/ikony_zarz/strzalki_trojkat.png' alt='' class='overlay' />
                    <div class='mouse'><img src='/images/nothing.gif' alt='' /> &nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                                    <script type='text/javascript'>
                    GarageDoor.scrollY = -55;
                    GarageDoor.setBindings('garagedoor');
                </script>


            </div>
```

Comment: maybe its not working because you didnt say what isnt working

Comment: added link, forget about this

Comment: You have still not said what is not working, all we know is that it is doing what is intended

Comment: ok, sorry - it show this picture `/ikony_zarz/strzalki_trojkat.png`, but Garage Door does not, it doesn't show text "SOMETHING ABOUT ME".

Comment: I just put this into a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/quant/v7Nrv/ and it seems like it's working to me. (I took the liberty of changing the image URLs and removing the nothing.gif image but it should be basically the same)

Comment: it could be a multitude of issues.  Are you sure that the .js files are on your server and in the location that your code is pointing to?  How about your css file?  Just a couple of things to verify.

Comment: i check css and js - everything is good with it. I try to put this code directly to .tpl page - and it works! but when code is on drupal page, it looks like that jquery and javascript doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for future - drupal CMS by default is blocking  tag, also in "Full HTML" editor. 
Problem resolved by using "PHP edit mode" or editing "Full HTML" mode to working with  tag.

Greetings